# How to use Utils from Chartjs on Django

Tags: python, django, chart.js

I have a simple **Django** project that display some charts on a determined page, so when I try to replicate some examples from [Chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked.html) I see that they make use of a [Utils](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/utils.html) module, when I make this same call in my `views.py` file it ends up returning **errors** since *`Utils` is not defined anywhere*

```py
@staff_member_required
def chart(request, year):
    persons = Persons.objects.filter(time__year=year)
    grouped_purchases = purchases.annotate(price=F('item__price')).annotate(month=ExtractMonth('time'))\
        .values('month').annotate(average=Sum('item__price')).values('month', 'average').order_by('month')

    sales_dict = get_year_dict()

    for group in grouped_purchases:
        sales_dict[months[group['month']-1]] = round(group['average'], 2)

    DATA_COUNT = 7;
    NUMBER_CFG = {count: DATA_COUNT, min: -100, max: 100}
    
    return JsonResponse({
        'title': f'Persons {year}',
        'data': {
            'labels': Utils.months({count: 7}),
            'datasets': [{
                'label': 'Amount ($)',
                'backgroundColor': Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
                'borderColor': colorPrimary,
                'data': Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
            }]
        },
    })
```

this is the header of the `html` file

```
  <head>
    <title>Statistics</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-v4-grid-only@1.0.0/dist/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  </head>
```

I know that `Utils` is a **JavaScript** file which I can't import in **Python**, there is a way to solve this?

Comment: "is there a way to solve this?"  No. You need to get the data to the page and then use javascript to get it into the chart. (or re-implement the utils module in Python yourself...)

Comment: I think re-implement `utils` is a very good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utils is a file written by chart.js itself that is not shipped with the library so you can't use it unless you implement it yourself. If you want to see what is in the file you can see the docs [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/utils.html)

File:

```js
import colorLib from '@kurkle/color';
import {DateTime} from 'luxon';
import 'chartjs-adapter-luxon';
import {valueOrDefault} from '../../dist/helpers.esm';

// Adapted from http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/
var _seed = Date.now();

export function srand(seed) {
  _seed = seed;
}

export function rand(min, max) {
  min = valueOrDefault(min, 0);
  max = valueOrDefault(max, 0);
  _seed = (_seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
  return min + (_seed / 233280) * (max - min);
}

export function numbers(config) {
  var cfg = config || {};
  var min = valueOrDefault(cfg.min, 0);
  var max = valueOrDefault(cfg.max, 100);
  var from = valueOrDefault(cfg.from, []);
  var count = valueOrDefault(cfg.count, 8);
  var decimals = valueOrDefault(cfg.decimals, 8);
  var continuity = valueOrDefault(cfg.continuity, 1);
  var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
  var data = [];
  var i, value;

  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    value = (from[i] || 0) + this.rand(min, max);
    if (this.rand() <= continuity) {
      data.push(Math.round(dfactor * value) / dfactor);
    } else {
      data.push(null);
    }
  }

  return data;
}

export function points(config) {
  const xs = this.numbers(config);
  const ys = this.numbers(config);
  return xs.map((x, i) => ({x, y: ys[i]}));
}

export function bubbles(config) {
  return this.points(config).map(pt => {
    pt.r = this.rand(config.rmin, config.rmax);
    return pt;
  });
}

export function labels(config) {
  var cfg = config || {};
  var min = cfg.min || 0;
  var max = cfg.max || 100;
  var count = cfg.count || 8;
  var step = (max - min) / count;
  var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
  var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
  var prefix = cfg.prefix || '';
  var values = [];
  var i;

  for (i = min; i < max; i += step) {
    values.push(prefix + Math.round(dfactor * i) / dfactor);
  }

  return values;
}

const MONTHS = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
];

export function months(config) {
  var cfg = config || {};
  var count = cfg.count || 12;
  var section = cfg.section;
  var values = [];
  var i, value;

  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    value = MONTHS[Math.ceil(i) % 12];
    values.push(value.substring(0, section));
  }

  return values;
}

const COLORS = [
  '#4dc9f6',
  '#f67019',
  '#f53794',
  '#537bc4',
  '#acc236',
  '#166a8f',
  '#00a950',
  '#58595b',
  '#8549ba'
];

export function color(index) {
  return COLORS[index % COLORS.length];
}

export function transparentize(value, opacity) {
  var alpha = opacity === undefined ? 0.5 : 1 - opacity;
  return colorLib(value).alpha(alpha).rgbString();
}

export const CHART_COLORS = {
  red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
  yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
  green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
  blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
  purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
  grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};

const NAMED_COLORS = [
  CHART_COLORS.red,
  CHART_COLORS.orange,
  CHART_COLORS.yellow,
  CHART_COLORS.green,
  CHART_COLORS.blue,
  CHART_COLORS.purple,
  CHART_COLORS.grey,
];

export function namedColor(index) {
  return NAMED_COLORS[index % NAMED_COLORS.length];
}

export function newDate(days) {
  return DateTime.now().plus({days}).toJSDate();
}

export function newDateString(days) {
  return DateTime.now().plus({days}).toISO();
}

export function parseISODate(str) {
  return DateTime.fromISO(str);
}
```